# Cannot open files created on windows in ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 17.10, windows-10

On my system I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10. I also have a third partition where I save files that I then mount when logging on ubuntu. In that partition I also have my onedrive folder. On windows the file is fine and I am able to access all the sub folders. On ubuntu though the file is not recognized and I cannot open it. Anyone knows of any solutions?

Comment: is one drive actually storing the file or just a reference file that points to the file's location on Microsoft's servers?

Comment: The title is misleading. Your beef is with OneDrive, not with "files created in Windows". To access your OneDrive account look for a OneDrive client for Ubuntu.

Comment: it should be actually storing the files as on ubuntu 16.14 even though I did not use any onedrive sync on ubuntu i could still access the pre existing files

Answer (score 0):

You should have a OneDrive client for Windows installed on your Windows partition, and a different OneDrive client for Ubuntu installed on your Ubuntu partition.  These two clients may be called the same thing, but they are not programmed the same way, so their code is very different.  Your Ubuntu system cannot recognize the information for files or programs created for a Windows environment.  For Ubuntu to be able to open the file, the Ubuntu machine must have a program capable of reading the file.

Comment: Is this a change from 16.14? As in that version yes I was not able to synchronize the onedrive folder. But I could still open it and it's sub folders, and retrieve files. Are you aware of any Onedrive clients for Ubuntu?

Comment: I am aware of onedrive-d located here http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/one-drive-ubuntu-integration

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1. In Windows, go to the settings for OneDrive, and untick the option to ***Save space and download files as you use them*** on the ***Settings*** tab.
2. Sign out of your OneDrive account.
3. Go to your OneDrive folder (C:\Users\User_Profile\OneDrive), and delete or move the folder to a different location.
4. Reboot your PC.
5. Sign back into the OneDrive client, and let the sync complete.
6. Boot into Linux, and the folders and files should be accessible.